# Can't create cookies with javascript in IE7/IE8

Tags: javascript, cookies, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm using [simpleCart.js](https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/blob/master/simpleCart.js) to setup a cart on the website. The problem is the cookies will not be created in IE7/IE8. So every page refresh we lose the items in the cart.

I've been looking at the code and it appears as though simpleCart uses the [cookie functions from quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

The only information I can find as to why it would be failing is here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27197 something to do with how the cookies are set that IE doesn't like.

I modified the quirksmode function to look like this:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    value = value.replace(/\=/g, '~');
    console.log(name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/");
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
    console.log(name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/");
}
```

And here is the output:

```
sc_simpleCart_1=id~c2||name~British%20Curry%20Powder||price~3.5||quantity~4; expires=Thu, 18 Aug 2011 15:58:16 GMT; path=/
sc_simpleCart_1=id%7Ec2%7C%7Cname%7EBritish%2520Curry%2520Powder%7C%7Cprice%7E3.5%7C%7Cquantity%7E4; expires=Thu, 18 Aug 2011 15:58:16 GMT; path=/
```

I thought that maybe it was something to do with the space characters, but I replaced them with hyphens and it made no difference.

There is actually a live version of the site here: http://www.bitspicy.com/bit-spicy-shop.php try adding an item to the cart and refresh the page in IE8 to see the issue for yourself.

Many thanks,
Rich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.

Basically the simpleCart.js is using a slightly modified version of the quirksmode functions, they were using the escape() and unescape() functions on the cookie data and IE didn't like that at all.

I simply replaced them with the originals and it works!